# ASP.Net-MVC-3 Beginner problems with ViewModels and submitting them back to the controller

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, viewmodel

I have build my entities via database-first, since I have to use an existing db.

Now, let's say I've got the entity customer and country and I want to edit the customer.
My View should contain something like First Name, Last Name and Country which is a DropdownList from all countries in the entity.
For that I created a CustomerViewModel which uses these two entities. But I dont' know if all of this is right, since some things don't work.

First the code of my CustomerViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public CUSTOMER customer { get; set; }
    public COUNTRY country { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> countryList { get; set; }

    MyEFEntities db = new MyEFEntities();

    public CustomerViewModel(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<CUSTOMER> customerList = from c in db.CUSTOMER
                                             where c.CUSTOMERNO== id
                                             select c;
        customer = customerList.First();

        var countryListTemp = new List<String>();
        var countryListQry = from s in db.COUNTRY
                             select s.COUNTRY_ABBREVIATION;
        countryListTemp.AddRange(countryListQry);
        countryList = new SelectList(countryListTemp);
    }
}
```

Then the CustomerController.cs:

```
public ViewResult CustomerData(int id = 0)
{
    // if (id == 0) { ... }
    var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel(id);
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerData(CustomerViewModel model)
{
    db.Entry(model.customer).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View(model);
}
```

And last but not least the CustomerData.cshtml:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer";
}
<h2>
    Customer</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("CustomerData", "Customer"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#data">Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#stuff">Stuff</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="data">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Encode("Country:")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.country.COUNTRY_ABBREVIATION, Model.countryList, Model.customer.ADDRESS.COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ABBREVIATION)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Encode("Last name:")
                @Html.TextBox("lastName", @Model.customer.ADDRESS.NAME)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Encode("First Name:")
                @Html.TextBox("firstName", @Model.customer.ADDRESS.FIRSTNAME)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hobbies">
            <p>
                Hobbies
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="stuff">
            <p>
                Stuff
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```

Viewing works great. I get to the URL http://localhost:12345/Customer/CustomerData/4711 and can see the current values for that customer.

Now, I'm missing some stuff.

1. The Save-button doesn't work. If I click it, I got an error message, that no parameterless constructor was found for this object. But I want to pass the ViewModel back to the controller. How to overload the Html.BeginForm() method?!
2. How to I store the changed values from the customer? Is is done by editing the text-fields or do I have to use Html.TextboxFor() instead of Html.Textbox? This is so complicated for a beginner. I'm not into the LINQ style at all.
3. The Dropdownlist doesn't work as supposed to. The country the customer has already is twice in it. It seems, that the third parameter does not preselct an item but add a default one. Would Html.Dropdownlist be better?

Answer (score 0):

This design is bad, I'm afraid. Never do DB access from the model, that is what the Controller is for. The model should just hold data that the Controller feeds to it.

If you factor out DB access, or any type of logic, from your model, you will find that your system becomes much easier to set up and maintain, and it probably even solves the problems you mention.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, too. Google was my friend. Could you please provide some more infos?

Comment: When your Model consists of properties filled up by your controller, you can then bind textboxes etc. to those properties using @Html.EditorFor, as in @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeProperty).

Comment: Should there be an empty consttructor in the ViewModel? And should I use the IEnumerable<SelectListItem> country in it? I'm a bit stuck, since this is all new to me.

Comment: Yes, your ViewModel should have either a parameterless constructor or no constructor at all.

What you can do is have a parameterless constructor that fills in default values, such as a Countries list. You will also need a property in your ViewModel for the selected country. Then you can combine the list and the selected country property in a call to @Html.DropDownFor.

Comment: Sorry for asking such silly questions. After putting the DB access into the controller, I could use the button to geht to the Http-POST method of CustomerData(CustomerViewModel model), but the db.SaveChanges() call leads to a DbUpdateConcurrencyException (0 changed rows). Second: I already use DropdownListFor with the selected item. But that is just added as default. So the selected item is twice in the list. I would need some working code, I think.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.tampadev.org/News/Details/ASPNETMVCSampleApplicationsOpenSourceExamplesTutorials

Comment: I already did some tutorials which worked fine, even with updating data in the db. I even read the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework" besides working on this project. But that doesn't help me for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I found out that it works if I use the entity CUSTOMER as the model. When using my own CustomerViewModel (with country inside) it doesn't work. Why? Can't I use ViewModels for POST data?